# Display a calendar with content in the days of the month

Tags: php, modx

I am attempting to build an overview of all my users' availability. Basically a page that hosts a large calendar and within each day it would show a user if they are "available". Here is a quick overview of how it works (very easy):

A user enters their availability which I save to the database as `startDate` and `endDate`. This is in UNIX timestamp.

What I tried applying was building a calendar with html and PHP, which was successful however I'm confused about how to query the database to match up the user's availability with the day. Here is what I tried:

```
$app = $modx->newQuery('modUserProfile');
$app->leftJoin('mxCalendarsEvents','mxCalendarsEvents',array('mxCalendarsEvents.createdby = modUserProfile.internalKey'));
$app->where(array('mxCalendarsEvents.startdate:LIKE' => $dayOfMonth));
$userId = $modx->getCollection('modUserProfile',$app);
```

The variable `$dayOfMonth` should be a UNIX timestamp of each day but I suppose that is my issue - how would I obtain that? I hope this makes sense...please let me know if I should expand on the question. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out today, wanted to help people out if they view this in the future.

Here is what I did:

1) Used a simple jQuery plugin called FullCalendar http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

2) Then I just query the database for the events and loop through them (after formatting the unix time to yyyy-mm-dd), using the above calendar's 'EVENT' function http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_array/.

3)That's it! I hope anyone referencing this in the future finds it helpful.